# Database for vehicle manufactury, but unknown exact items

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

Assume I have an imaginary factory for building different kinds of `vehicles`: cars, buses, pickups, etc...

Each of these vehicles is built up of many different `materials`: doors, door openers, wheels, etc...

I have a template for each vehicle type: e.g. a car consists of 4 wheels (regardless of the wheel model, size, or brand).

A customer buys a vehicle of type car, and now I want to specify the **brand** of the tyre. How can I differentiate now between the template which builds a vehicle and the exact item codes of which this specific car is built of?

**Update1:**

My goals are to be able to:

- make a (general) template for each vehicle
- build a concrete vehicle (with all materials used)

Suppose a car needs 4 door handles. I mention in this in the template. However, I have e.g. 4 kinds of door handles: a, b, c, & d. I cannot mention this in the template bec. it depends on the customer choice later on.
After a while I build a car and I use handle kind b.

My question is how can I have the proper setup/relationships for templates, all materials, and real vehicles?

Comment: This is a basic database design issue, not a programming question.

Comment: and did I mention something about programming?

Comment: Not you, but: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

An individual car and tyre brand needs to be a 1:1 relationship.  It ought to be a simple query.

Your database schema and the template that builds a specific car in memory are two separate issues.  Which one are you really asking about?

Comment: Not enough.  This question is too broad and should either be refined or closed.